# How to prove this without using sequences?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map, then $T$ is injective if and only if there exists $C > 0$ such that $|T(x)|\geq C|x|$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now, I've heard that there's a proof of this fact using sequences and showing that $C$ is the infimum of the set $\{|T(x)|/|x| : x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, but I was wondering if there's another proof.

I've thought in some connection between this and the definition of the norm of $T$ that is sometimes defined by $|T|=\sup\{|T(y)| : y \in S^{n-1}\}$, but I couldn't see how to really use this.

Can someone give a hint on how to prove this fact without the use of sequences?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Consider the set $T(S^{n-1})$. $T$ is injective if and only if that doesn't contain $0$.

Comment: if you have linear maps you can use that a linear iff its kernel is trivial. If $y\in \ker T$ then $\|T(y)\|=0 \geq C\| y\|$ hence $\|y\|=0\implies y=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use the same idea you mentioned without bringing in sequences, observing that given $T$ injective, $ g : S^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by $ g(x) = |T(x)| $ is continuous with a compact image and $ g(x) > 0 $ for all $ x \in S^{n-1} $, hence has a minimum $C > 0 $. Thus $|T(x/|x|)| \geq C $ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} $. Converse is trivial.